# linq query to list that adds position of result

Tags: linq

I have the linq query that produces the result below:

```
var result = from x in model.SITEs 
              where x.SiteId == homeSite 
              select new  { x.SiteId,
                            x.SiteAlloc1,
                            x.SiteAlloc2,
                            x.SiteAlloc3,
                            x.SiteAlloc4 });



SiteId  SiteAlloc1  SiteAlloc2  SiteAlloc3  SiteAlloc4
======================================================
1           5           3           2           4
```

But what I need is something more like this, where the `Rank` is the position of the `SiteId` in the result.

```
SiteId      Rank
==================
1           1
2           4
3           3
4           5
5           2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = from x in model.SITEs 
          where x.SiteId == homeSite 
          select new  { x.SiteId,
                        x.SiteAlloc1,
                        x.SiteAlloc2,
                        x.SiteAlloc3,
                        x.SiteAlloc4 }).
          Select((t,u) => new { 
                        SiteId = t.SiteId,
                        SiteAlloc1 = t.SiteAlloc1,
                        SiteAlloc2 = t.SiteAlloc2,
                        SiteAlloc3 = t.SiteAlloc3,
                        SiteAlloc4 = t.SiteAlloc4, 
                        Rank = u + 1));
```

Where u is the index (0 based, that's why I added 1), or in your case the rank and t is the selected object

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. But it doesn't like the `= SiteId` in the line `Select((t,u) => new { SiteId = SiteId, Rank = u + 1));`

Comment: sorry it should have been t.SiteId, i updated the answer

Comment: That works for only the first column `SiteId` but not for the other columns (`SiteAlloc1, SiteAlloc2, SiteAlloc3, SiteAlloc4`)

Comment: what's your expected result exactly? the question just says SiteId and Rank

Comment: The expected result is shown in the original question. The values for the cloumns `SiteAlloc1, SiteAlloc2, SiteAlloc3, SiteAlloc4` are actually a `SiteId` but named differently and need to be included in the result.

Comment: wouldn't the rank be the same one for the entire line? i updated the answer if this isn't what you need please post the full expected result, i can't figure out what you want

Comment: The values displayed in the row `SiteId  SiteAlloc1  SiteAlloc2  SiteAlloc3  SiteAlloc4` are all actually refer to `SiteId`. The `Rank` is also in order from left to right.